# How do I resolve a callback error with 'callback' is an instance of Object)?

Tags: react-native

> TypeError: callback is not a function. (In 'callback(data)',
> 'callback' is an instance of Object)

The code here works just fine when I write it like this:

```
const onSelectFilterDone = (filter) => {
    setFilter(filter);
    setFilterModalVisible(false);

    unsubscribe.current = listingsAPI.subscribeListings(
      { categoryId: category.id },
      // { categoryId2: category2.id },
      favorites,
      onListingsUpdate,
    );
  };
```

When i uncomment that other line, it breaks and gives me this error.

```
const onSelectFilterDone = (filter) => {
    setFilter(filter);
    setFilterModalVisible(false);

    unsubscribe.current = listingsAPI.subscribeListings(
      { categoryId: category.id },
      { categoryId2: category2.id },
      favorites,
      onListingsUpdate,
    );
  };
```

Here is the relevant snippet from listingsAPI (below) if it helps but this code works fine when there is only one object. Is there a specific way to make this work with two objects like above?

```
if (categoryId) {
    return (
      listingsRef
        .where('categoryID', '==', categoryId)
        .where('isApproved', '==', isApproved)
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const data = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const listing = doc.data();
            if (favorites && favorites[doc.id] === true) {
              listing.saved = true;
            }
            data.push({ ...listing, id: doc.id });
          });
          callback(data);
        })
    );
  }

  if (categoryId2) {
    return (
      listingsRef
        .where('categoryID2', '==', categoryId2)
        .where('isApproved', '==', isApproved)
        .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const data = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const listing = doc.data();
            if (favorites && favorites[doc.id] === true) {
              listing.saved = true;
            }
            data.push({ ...listing, id: doc.id });
          });
          callback(data);
        })
    );
  }
```

Comment: How are you declaring `subscribeListings` function?

Comment: @Tj3n looks like the long snippet at the end of my question with this code leading: ```export const subscribeListings = (
  { userId, categoryId, categoryId2, isApproved = true },
  favorites,
  callback,
) => {
  if ...```

Comment: You function call should be `listingsAPI.subscribeListings(
      { categoryId: category.id, categoryId2: category2.id },
      favorites,
      onListingsUpdate,
    )`

Comment: @Tj3n Thanks, no error now but it doesn't produce what I want.

Comment: I've added the answer that do combine FB queries that might works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your queries via this way if you want to have it optional:

```
let query = listingsRef.where('isApproved', '==', isApproved)

if (categoryId) {
  query = query.where('categoryID', '==', categoryId)
}

if (categoryId2) {
  query = query.where('categoryID2', '==', categoryId2)
}

query.onSnapshot...
```

Comment: Strangely this too doesn't work. I am trying to get all categoryId and categoryId2

Comment: Weird, it should works doesn't matter if you have passed categoryId and/or categoryId2, try log out your function params before executing code.